# font-face with bold weight not being recognized

Tags: css, reactjs, fonts

I am using 2 `@font-face` on my `index.css` file with the purpose of using a font in regular weight and in bold weight as my default font in my entire application:

**index.css file:**

```
body {
    padding: 0px;
    margin:0px;
    font-family: "LucidaGrande";
}


@font-face {
  font-family: 'LucidaGrande';
  src: local('LucidaGrande'), url(../assets/fonts/LucidaGrande.ttf) format('truetype');
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'LucidaGrande';
  font-weight: 900;
  src: local('LucidaGrande'), url(../assets/fonts/LucidaGrandeBold.ttf) format('truetype');
}
```

Now, the regular weight seems to be working for the entire application, however, on an other part of my application I am trying to use the font in bold weight like this:

```
#presentation-text em{
    font-size: 35px;
    color: rgb(139, 59, 28);
    font-style: normal; 
    font-weight: 900;
  }
```

However the `900` i.e the **bold weight** is not being applied, still regular.

Am I using this correctly?

Comment: Does LucidaGrandeBold actually contain a 900 weight font? I mean, does 700 work?

Comment: dont know if 900 but yeah I checked the fonts and they are clearly different being the bold version way bolder than the regular version

Comment: Where exacty did you get the font from? I can't seem to find a more recent version than from 1999.

Comment: mmm, i see....well I got them from someone else, I will try to find out, maybe the problem is just in the fonts

Comment: but @MrLister, does my code above seem correct to you?, just to discard possibilities

Comment: Yes, I don't see any problems with your css. But are you sure it's working without the font? When removing all references to Lucida Grande, is the `em` bold? What does your HTML look like?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're using `@font-face`, *never* use `local(...)`. The whole reason you're using `@font-face` is to ensure that *you* control *exactly* which font resource gets loaded for which (set of) font properties. The last thing you want is for the OS to black-box fetch you what *it* thinks the font is for the name you specified. Even if it really does find Lucida Grande for some user, there is zero guarantee it's going to be the same version you have installed on your development machine.

Interestingly that actually tangential to the real problem here: the way you've written your CSS right now means that, because you have the font installed locally, whatever follows `local(...)` will never even be looked at by the browser, similar to what happens when you're using `font-family: serif, Times`. The browser knows how to resolve the first thing, so it immediately stops: it already found what it needed to find.

Effectively your current CSS, running in a browser on your own machine, says this, as far as the browser is concerned:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'LucidaGrande';
  src: local('LucidaGrande);
}

@font-face {
  font-family: 'LucidaGrande';
  font-weight: 900;
  src: local('LucidaGrande);
}
```

So you're loading the exact same thing in both declarations. As CSS weights for the text shaper in the browser are entirely independent from the system text engine, the result is exactly what you're seeing: both rules declare *the same font resource* as the one to use when you say `font-family: LucidaGrande`, both with or without `font-weight: 900`.

Drop `local(...)` and it'll instead work exactly as you need it to.

Also, you'll want to turn those `.ttf` files into WOFF2 and then load those, because they're much smaller, as well as a promise to the browser that these are indeed unencumbered webfonts.

Comment: have to admit that you answer was a looooot of wording just to say "remove the `local(...)`" but hey!!, this WORKS, and I just must say THANK YOU!.

Comment: And apparently still not enough if all you took away from this was"remove local". The _real_ problem was that you told the browser to use the same asset for different font properties. You obviously have to remove `local` because it makes no sense for `@font-face`, but the _problem_ was you repeated yourself instead of specifying different rules.